# PHP time ahead by one day

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have some functionality that depends on whether something has already happened in time.
Currently, I do something like this:

```
$hike_time = strtotime($month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year.' '.$start_time);
if($hike_time < mktime())
{
  // Do stuff :)
}
```

But I need to wait a day or twelve hours (not sure yet) until I change the functionality.
How can I make the mktime() be +1 day or +12 hours?

In terms of UX, how are such event-based UX quirks typically handled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()`.

```
$tomorrow = strtotime('+1 day');

var_dump(
   date(DATE_RFC850, time()), // string(30) "Monday, 28-Mar-11 05:48:47 UTC"
   date(DATE_RFC850, $tomorrow) // string(31) "Tuesday, 29-Mar-11 05:48:47 UTC"
);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/zz9HT0OP).

Comment: Thanks Alex, do you mean to literally put '+1 day' or the string I have above and surround it with round braces and then '+1 day' ?  Just pasting your code didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Genadinik Yes, that code *as is*. Check the [CodePad](http://codepad.org/zz9HT0OP). That will add one day to the current PHP time.

Answer (score 1):

Strtotime gives the time in something called the unix time stamp. This is the number of seconds sense January first 1970.  So the number you get, you can add and subtract the number of seconds you want.
aka for 12 hours in the future
`$hike_time = strtotime($month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year.' '.$start_time) + (60 * 60 * 12);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$tomorrow=date("M-d-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$day+1,$month,$year));
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution, add the number of seconds in a day (86400).

Comment: Not all days have 86400 seconds (DST, leap seconds, etc...)

Comment: Daylight savings time is a timezone switch, but typically you'll operate on times within one timezone and then convert. As for leap seconds, perhaps you'll convert to TAI before you add 84600.